# Purely real or complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Is $\cos(i\dfrac{\pi}{3})$ a purely real or a complex number?

My try : from de moivres,

$\cos x=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, what should I do with this?

Comment: Well, have you tried plugging $x=i\pi/3$ into that formula?

Answer (score 3):

$\cos z=1-\dfrac{z^2}{2}+\dfrac{z^4}{4!}-\ldots$

Put $z=\dfrac{i\pi}{3}$

Do there exist any term containing $i$ in that expression anymore?

Comment: Maybe $4!$, no ?

Answer (score 3):

Simply plug $x=i\pi/3$ into the formula
$$\cos(i\pi/3)=\frac{e^{i\cdot i\pi/3}+e^{-i\cdot i\pi/3}}{2}=\frac{e^{-\pi/3}+e^{\pi/3}}{2}\in\mathbb{R}.$$
So $\cos(i\pi/3)$ is purely real (the imaginary part of any real number is zero).

Comment: That is cool, but how does that prove the imaginary part to be zero?

Comment: @Zlatan The imaginary part of any real number is zero, because if $x\in\mathbb R$, then $x=x + 0\cdot i$.

Comment: @Zlatan: this is not only "cool", it also precisely answers your question.